# Indexing multiple array/ matrix elements similar to matlab "var[1:10]" in C

Tags: c, arrays, matlab, matrix, indexing

for my calculations i need to index into an array. I am used to MATLAB where you can index in a way such as

```
var[1:10]  // extracts the first through to the 10th element of "var"
```

I am trying to find a similar principle in C without the use of loops if possible. From research I can only see loops being used.

If this is the only method, then can `#define` or similar be used to create a macro that when you write `[start:end]` it implements a loop, but not seen in the `main` code?

I have written a basic loop that could be implemented behind the scenes as it were if there is a way to specify that this is what you want to use in the `[start:end]` scenario.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int array[10] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    int start = 3;
    int end = 8;
    int var[5];
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        var[j] = array[i];
        j++;
    }

    printf("%d", var[5]);
}
```

Am I trying to do something impossible or impractical? For what I am trying to do, writing a loop or calling a function would clutter up the code more than I would prefer.

Comment: If you just want to access part of an array using different indices, you can set a pointer to the element you want to have index 0, such as `int *var = array + 3`. Then `var[0]` is `array[3]`, `var[1]` is `array[4]`, `var[-1]` is `array[-2]`, and so on. To be strictly conforming (fully portable) C code, this is limited to setting `var` to point to an array element or one past the end of the array—you should not try to set `int *var = array - 1;` so that `var[1]` would be `array[0]`.

Comment: C uses loops. Get used to it. This is the natural way to code in C. MATLAB is an interpreted language in which looping over elements of an array *used to be* significantly slower than vectorized functions (this is less true since JIT). Those vectorized functions were faster because they are written in C. Using loops.

Comment: The code you post is broken and accesses array elements out of bounds. `int var[5]` has five elements and can be indexed only up to `var[4]`.

Comment: If you want to use a low-level language, I would recommend C++ instead. Then you can use a library like Eigen, which has indexing similar to MATLAB’s. C++ allows for more expressive syntax than C. If you want to use C, you will have to get used to writing lots of loops and doing things by manipulating pointers and calling functions. You will not be able to modify its syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'm trying to learn C for a job I'm applying for so I will indeed have to "get used to it". Personally I quite like the indexing syntax of matlab, but as has been said, if that's not the C way then I'll have to learn to like loops etc

Comment: Exactly, every language has its idioms. You wouldn't even do things the same way between C, C++ and C#. (We won't even talk about Objective C.) Coming from MATLAB or Python or R is a much bigger leap.

Answer (score 2):

*extracting* a subarray from an array may have 2 very different meanings:

- you can act on a subarray by passing a pointer to the `start` element and a length of `end - start` to a function that expects a ponter to an array of `int` and a length.
- note however that if the function modifies this subarray, the changes will occur in the original array too, since you are acting on a portion of this array.
- note too that array index values start at `0` in C, unlike MATLAB, so a slice of 10 elements at the start of `a` has index values `0` to `9`.
- if you want the extracted subarray to not interfere with the original array, you need a separate array, either defined as in your example or allocated from the heap with `malloc` or `calloc`.

Here is a modified version of your code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void print_array(const char *msg, const int *a, int count) {
    printf("%s", msg);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf(" %d", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    int array[10] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    int start = 3;  // start from the third element
    int end = 8;    // stop before the 8th element
    int var[5];     // the extracted slice has 8-3=5 elements indeed

    // print the original array
    print_array("original array:", array, 10);

    // print the slice of the original array from 3 to 8
    print_array("subarray array[3:8]:", array + 3, 8 - 3);

    // extract a copy of the subarray
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        var[i - start] = array[i];
    }

    // print the extracted array:
    print_array("extracted array:", var, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = start; i <= end; i++){

    var[j] = array[i];

    j++;

}
```

in your code your'e indexing i from 3 to 8 including 8 (because of the <= sign instead of < sign ) with causes 6 iterations, where your j array only has 5 elements. your'e going out of boundary.

There is no way to change the syntax as you want in C, but if you just want to pass an array to somewhere else, you can pass a pointer to it. just be sure to not to declare the array inside the function, but in global space.

if you want to do some operations on arrays, you have to do it element by element in loops and its better to write a function for this instead of macros.

Comment: thanks, I'm still getting used to a lower-level language than matlab, i will change <= to <, and persevere with loops and functions. Still working on pointers so will look into that

Answer (score 1):

You can use the library function memcpy, declared in string.h, like this. Note that it is you responsibility to ensure that there is enough room in the destination.

```
#include    <stdlib.h> // for EXIT_SUCCESS
#include    <stdio.h>  // for printf
#include    <string.h> // for memcpy
int main( void)
{
int array[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int start = 3;
int end = 8;
int var[6]; 
    memcpy( var, array+start, (end+1-start)*sizeof array[0]);
    printf("%d\n", var[5]);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you wanted instead to copy a sequence from array to another part of array (ie if the source and destimation overlap) you should use memmove instead. It has the same calling convention.

C is low-level compared to python. Writing C well means getting to know its standard libraries.